# Last Login in number of days format

Tags: functions, user-meta

I am trying to capture last user active date and reproduce that into another user-meta field in days only without any text with it. Being very bad with coding, I was hoping someone could help me shed some light on how best to achieve this.

I checked many other solutions in the forum but non worked the way I wanted.

Currently I am using this:

```
function set_user_last_active( $user_id ) {
$user = get_userdata ( $user_id );

$dateoflast = strtotime( get_user_meta($user_id, 'last_active') );             
$datenow = strtotime( current_time('mysql') );
$difference = abs($datenow - $dateoflast / 86400);

//add or update the last login value for logged in user
update_usermeta( $user->ID, 'last_active', current_time('mysql') );
update_usermeta( $user->ID, 'last_active_days_ago', human_time_diff( strtotime( get_user_meta($user_id, 'last_active', true) ) ) );
update_usermeta( $user->ID, 'last_active_days_ago2', $difference);                              
}
```

As you can see, I am trying different ways to achieve this but the closest I got to is the second update_usermeta which outputs a number along with minutes.

Although I took the third one from a post here, it outputs a long number that keeps increasing: 1387740860

I hope I can find someone who tried a similar thing or experienced enough to help me do it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you specify the output value? An output in days could possibly result in something like `0.00752314814815` if the last action is only a few minutes ago...

Comment: @Sven It didn't occur to me that this may have been reason. I tried this using a user that would a value less than a day. But occurring to your comment, there should be a 0 and some numbers?

Comment: @Sven Sorry for the last comment which was full of typos! Couldn't edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there are a couple of things to do:

- Get `last_active` for the user
- Calculate the days since `last_active`
- Set `last_active_days_ago` for the user

So you can go like this:

```
function daysAgo( $time ) {
  $time = time() - $time;
  $daysAgo = $time / 86400; // calculate days
    return $daysAgo;
}

function set_user_last_active_days_ago( $user_id ) {
  // get last time active
  $time = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'last_active', true );

  if ( !empty($time) ) :
    // calculate time since last_active
    $time = daysAgo( strtotime($time) );
    // update user meta
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_active_days_ago', $time );
  endif;
}

set_user_last_active_days_ago( get_current_user_id() );
```

You'll also have to set `last_active` somewhere:

```
function set_user_last_active( $user_id ) {
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_active', date('Y-m-d H:i:s') );
}

set_user_last_active( get_current_user_id() );
```

Note: You can also pass in a custom user ID within `set_user_last_active` and `set_user_last_active_days_ago` instead of the current user ID.

**Update:** You can call `set_user_last_active` and `set_user_last_active_days_ago` within every action you'd like to. Let's say you want to set `last_active` every time a user logged in to WordPress:

```
add_action('wp_login', 'user_login_last_active', 10, 2);
function user_login_last_active($user_login, $user) {
  set_user_last_active( $user->ID );
}
```

It's completely up to you when you want to set the data. It can be set per login (like above) or e.g. every time a [post is saved](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) or the [profile is updated](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/personal_options_update).

If none of these actions will fit your need you can take a look the available [Actions at the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category%3aActions).

Comment: Thanks a lot Sven! This is working great! With regard to the last 2x set_user lines you wrote, would this be a good way to implement them?

    if( is_page() OR is_single() ) {
 set_user_last_active( get_current_user_id() );
 set_user_last_active_days_ago( get_current_user_id() );
    } else {}

I am thinking of attaching this to wp_footer as add action to track the last activity of the user.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is the more final version I am planning to use:

  add_action( 'wp_footer', 'educadme_global_lastactive_update' );
  function educadme_global_lastactive_update() {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      set_user_last_active( get_current_user_id() );
      set_user_last_active_days_ago( get_current_user_id() );
      
     } else {}
   }

Comment: @A.Hariri Hey, I updated my answer with and an example on how to use it. Hope this will help you, but you're on the right track anyway :)